# RestTemplate: How to get the raw response

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate to access a service.

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate ();
HttpEntity <String> he = new HttpEntity <String> (output, hh);
ResponseEntity <String> re = rt.exchange ("http://localhost:8080/my", HttpMethod.GET, he, String.class);
```

*ResponseEntity* has *getBody* and *getHeaders* for accessing the response.
*getHeaders* is already a parsed list of the header-lines.

Is there a way I can get the raw response as one big junk of bytes?

Answer (score 2):

For that you will use following signature of `execute` method :

```
   execute(URI url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback, ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor)
```

This method will execute the HTTP method to the given URL, preparing the request with the RequestCallback, and reading the response with a ResponseExtractor.

Next step is to write a custom implementation for [ResponseExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseExtractor.html) interface and override `extractData()` which is responsible for extracting data from response.

Here is example.
First, write some dummy method in controller class, something like this :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/hello")
public String test() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

Then, write method which will call method above using `restTemplate` and return response as **byte** array:

```
 @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() throws IOException {
        final URI url = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/hello");
        final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
        // Here you can set headers, request body,query parans,ect..
        RequestCallback requestCallback = r -> {
            //example: r.getBody().write(("username=" + username).getBytes());
            r.getHeaders().setAll(headers);
        };
        byte[] res = restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, new ResponseExtractor<byte[]>() {

            @Override
            public byte[] extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                // return data from response as byte array
                response.getBody().read(data);
                return data;
            }
        });
        //write result in console
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStr
                = new ByteArrayInputStream(res);
        int b = 0;
        while ((b = byteArrayInputStr.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) b;
            System.out.println("Char : " + ch);
        }

    }
```

If you execute `test()` method, you should see output like this:

[image]

Comment: As far I see this still separates header and body because it is already separated in ClientHttpResponse. What I want is the raw data of the response - starting witht he 1st byte received.